# Redirect to node app in Django

Tags: python, django, nginx

So I'm running a server with Django, and I want the root url to point to a meteor app on the same server.  I'm trying to figure how how to call that from within django.  I'm new to Django and meteor and nginx.. I'm usually a LAMP guy.

So am I supposed to use the URLs thing in Django and point to main.js?  Or do I need to create a view and have the view execute the main.js?

Thank you

Comment: The fact they're on the same server is irrelevant, you have two web apps and need a way to communicate between them, i.e a rest api or http requests

Comment: OK, so create a view that then does an HTTP request to the meteor app and echo out the results?  I guess if the meteor app is much more than a static page it will probably get pretty hairy doing it that way

Comment: Do meteor and django need to communicate? Do they share the database?

Comment: No, they don't at all